# Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Elie\Projects\MEAN\task-manager\api\index.js'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I have been following along this youtube playlist: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3R-8jj3S7U. We got to the part where we finished a model and are ready to test. Run `nodemon`command to start the API and I get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WWgK.png)

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCjGd.png) is the file in question as well

Thanks for the help

UPDATE: In the `package.json` file i changed main to the exact file path of `index.js` you can see the `package.json` file [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xREj3.png). This seemed to produce a better result but still didnt fix the issue. The error now reads `clean - exit waiting for changes before restart` and seems like it should be working but it isnt. I attached a sceengrab to have a better look. [View Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMgQo.png)

UPDATE #2: I changed the `main` property in the `package.json` file to `app.js` and ran `nodemon` command and produced this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCDbW.png). A bit of progress?

UPDATE #3: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOQuK.png) is my `app.js` file for reference

UPDATE #4: I updated my `express` property verision to include an actual verison number then ran `npm install` which seemed to be sucessful. I then ran `nodemon` again. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCmnu.png) are the results

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you've provided, I would guess you are executing nodemon by just typing the `nodemon` command without any arguments. This only works if your entry point is named `index.js`, but in the screenshot you provided it's clear that your entry point is named `app.js`, so you should be running nodemon with the following command:

```
nodemon app.js
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @rav2040. Let me explain more. In the package.json file the main is set to `index.js` and im executing the command exactly as followed `nodemon index.js` and that is producing the error above

Comment: Right, but you don't have a file called `index.js` in your project. So your options are:

1. Rename `app.js` to `index.js`
2. Rename the `main` property of `package.json` to `app.js`
3. Execute nodemon with the command I mention in my original answer: `nodemon app.js`

Any of those should work.

Comment: I checked your update. The `index.js` file in your models directory is not your application entry point. Your application entry point is just `app.js`. You  should be able to successfully start your application by doing any of the three things I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: I changed  `main` property to `app.js` and then a I just ran `nodemon` command and that produced a different error, `Error: Cannot find module 'express'`. I will update the question with the full screengrab

Comment: I'm not sure why, but your "express" dependency in `package.json` isn't set to an Express version number. You can fix that by changing `"file:node_modules/express"` to `"^4.17.1"` and then executing the command `npm install` to make sure that Express is installed properly.

Comment: updating new screengrabs now

Comment: It seems you don't actually have a MongoDB server running, so it's failing to connect. This web page contains instructions for installing MongoDB on Windows: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

Comment: Make sure you have a MongoDB server running on your computer before you start your application.

Comment: I will follow those instrutions and upate this tomorrow. It is pretty late here in the states

Comment: I actually got to it before I went to bed. I installed MongoDB and it seems to be working now. I was given a depricationWarning but I added `useUnifidedTopology = true` in my `mongoose.js` and that seemed to fix the issue. Once I did that I ran nodemon again and it worked I am receving requests now. Thank you!